# Find the tranfer function for this signal flow graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, signal-processing

[image: Find the tranfer function??]

I already sovle this by 2 different ways and had 2 different results. I don't know which one is right. Can someone use the matlab or something like that to solve this quickly to find the right answer. Sorry for my bad English.Here is my first solution, click the image to see better

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Keep in mind that this is not a website where people will give you ready-made answers/verification for questions.

Comment: I have added my effort to solve but not sure if it give the best result, can someone use some softwares to solve this quickly ??